# Without PIVOT, display data where GROUP BY column are the column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have data that looks like the following:

```
Name    Date         Hr     Min    Amt
Joe     20150320     08     00     5
Joe     20150320     08     15     3
Carl    20150320     09     30     1
Carl    20150320     09     45     2
Ray     20150320     13     00     8
Ray     20150320     13     30     6
```

A simple GROUP BY [Name], [Date], [Hr] would display the total by hour for each salesman.

Without using PIVOT or dynamic sql, how can I display this data where the hours are the columns? With PIVOT I would need to detail each hour, so if the data above were the only data, there would be 3 columns with data (8, 9, 13), and 21 empty columns.

The reason I want to do this is because I would like to create an SSRS report where the columns are the hours. Unfortunately, I can't use a matrix because I can't sort by the column detail (ie. click on "8" and display from smallest to largest); I've already confirmed this limitation with an MS expert.

So any help is appreciated. We have Sql Server 2008 R2.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by sorting by detail? What would be your page,column group, row group, and details? Could you give a quick example of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Name    
      ,[Date]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '00' THEN Amt END) [00]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '01' THEN Amt END) [01]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '02' THEN Amt END) [02]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '03' THEN Amt END) [03]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '04' THEN Amt END) [04]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '05' THEN Amt END) [05]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '06' THEN Amt END) [06]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '07' THEN Amt END) [07]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '08' THEN Amt END) [08]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '09' THEN Amt END) [09]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '10' THEN Amt END) [10]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '11' THEN Amt END) [11]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '12' THEN Amt END) [12]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '13' THEN Amt END) [13]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '14' THEN Amt END) [14]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '15' THEN Amt END) [15]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '16' THEN Amt END) [16]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '17' THEN Amt END) [17]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '18' THEN Amt END) [18]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '19' THEN Amt END) [19] 
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '20' THEN Amt END) [20]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '21' THEN Amt END) [21]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '22' THEN Amt END) [22]
      ,SUM(Case When Hr = '23' THEN Amt END) [23]
From TablenName
Group By Name ,[Date]
```

Comment: I had considered this, but it's the same result as PIVOT: if the data above were the only data, there would be 3 columns with data (8, 9, 13), and 21 empty columns.

Comment: In that case your only option is dynamic pivot.

Comment: Why not just set column visibility based on existing records?  Something like `=IIF(Count(Fields!agent.Value) = 0, true, false) `

Comment: I ended up using this solution. I tried using a dynamic pivot, and even though the resultset was correct, SSRS could not read the columns at design time. So I ended up using this solution since it's much cleaner and set the column visibility within SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

something like this work?? put your key fields into temp tables dont join them so you create a possibility for everything then sub query your amt in.

```
select * into #Temp1 from (
select '01' as 'Pivot_Hour'
union all
select '02' as 'Pivot_Hour'
union all 
select '03' as 'Pivot_Hour'
union all
select '04' as 'Pivot_Hour'
union all
select '05' as 'Pivot_Hour'
--Put all 24 hours in....
)  
x

select * into #Temp2 from (
select 'Carl' as 'User'
union all
select 'Joe' as 'User'
union all 
select 'Ray' as 'User'
union all
select 'Dave' as 'User'
union all
select 'Seve' as 'User'
---Could select distinct from your data...
)  
x


Select * into #Temp3 from (
select '20150321' as 'Date'
union all
select '20150322' as 'Date'
union all 
select '20150323' as 'Date'
union all
select '20150324' as 'Date'
union all
select '20150325' as 'Date'
---Could select distinct from your data...
)  
x

select * 
,(select sum(yrd.amt) from Yourdata Yrd 
where yrd.Name = t2.User 
and yrd.date = t3.date 
and yrd.Hr = t1.Pivot_Hour)Amt
from #Temp1 t1,#Temp2 t2,#Temp3 t3

drop table #Temp1
drop table #Temp2
drop table #Temp3
```